# About "nant::get-base-directory()"

Tags: function, nant

As in http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/functions/nant.get-base-directory.html, they explaint the meaning of this function is:

> The base directory of the appdomain in which NAnt is running.

I don't know what does **appdomain** mean! Someone please explain it for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, it's the location of your project from where the NAnt script gets called.

I use this in our NAnt scripts and store it in a local (and more friendly-looking) property such as:

```
<property name="project.local.folder" value="${string::replace(project::get-base-directory(), '\','/')}" dynamic="true"/>
```

... and then I can reference the ${project.local.folder} anywhere in the script without having to worry about it's content or it's location.

Hope this helps!